# How to make custom Keras layer without Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to experiment with Keras, and thought I would create my own layer. However, I am using an AMD GPU (PlaidML) without Tensorflow. I have seen some tutorials online, but they all require Tensorflow. How would I create a custom Keras layer without using Tensorflow?

Comment: You sound confused; Keras is actually just a *front-end* for Tensorflow, not a stand-alone framework.

Comment: @desertnaut I don't think there is a confusion, you are talking about the latest versions of keras and tf.keras, but earlier versions are still used by people, and those versions are still multi-backend.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy you are of course right, but still - Keras is a front-end, not a framework in itself; it cannot work without a backend, which is what OP seems to request here. Except if "without TF" means "with a different backend"...?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I am using Keras with the PlaidML backend, so I cannot use Tensorflow functions.